# I seem to have lost over 2500 rep today. Could this be on purpose?

Tags: bug, reputation

I seem to have an anomalous drop in rep.  **2656 points** gone in the past hour.  I know that the ways of SO are fleet and mysterious, but I would really like to know what triggers this, if not a bug.

[image: 2656 reputation drop]

Since I also see that my username was changed (from NewAlexandria), I presume this is probably a bug.   Any insight is appreciated.  I've left my contact info in the shot in case anyone needs to contact me directly about the tech details.  I also seem to have lost all my badges - so I'm thinking *bug*, or I garnered some kind of extreme ban-punishment.  This is the only SO profile affected.

Note: I've received some upvotes, and my rep didn't correct.

[image: evidence of illegal name change]

Comment: This unfortunately is a bug that the developers are trying to track down. Your rep will eventually fix itself, but you will have to correct your name.

Comment: I recently completed an Area51 commitment.  It's an uncommon event and maybe something wasn't tested?

Comment: @NewAlexandria no, don't think it's related to Area51. you're the latest victim of a very weird bug, your rep will fix itself soon when you'll get upvotes (or downvotes) and I see you already changed your name back.

Comment: No, nothing to do with Area51. We are still tracking down why these happen and hopefully will figure it out soon.

Comment: Pity all the Meta.SO rep doesn't count on SO! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've received some upvotes, and my rep didn't correct

Comment: This would fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @user689 no it won't, they removed the option to trigger recalc so they can track the bug down.

Comment: @NewAlexandria you got only +15 from answer getting accepted, not really an upvote just yet. No worry, your rep will come back. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard so I'm free of the carbonite, but my voice will return in time?